# Ubuntu17.10 doesn't recognize VGA display

Tags: multiple-monitors, 17.10, external-monitor

Week ago I installed Ubuntu17.10 on my laptop. I'm using two external displays one HDMI and one old VGA monitor (built-in screen I'm not using at all), it worked like a charm for a week except resetting Display configs after reboot. Yesterday I disconnected monitors and today Ubuntu doesn't recognize VGA display, in the settings I see 'Unknown display' and black screen on the monitor but I can move windows and mouse to that screen.

I don't' think it's a driver issue because before everything worked. Also yesterday I install some Ubuntu updates, maybe it's the issue?

Can anyone help me find a solution, thanks??!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was the issue, but after tons of different combinations (turn cable on/off, trying different cable, different display settings )it started work :)